# Counterexample or proof of function such that every point is fixed implies function is identity or constant

Tags: functions, fixed-points

I've been trying to prove the following for a while, out of curiosity. For any (possibly discontinuous, etc) function $f:A\to A$ such that
$$
f^n(x) = f(x),\quad \forall x\in A, n\in \mathbb{N}
$$
where $f^n$ is the $n$-repeated application of the function $f$ on its argument, then $f$ is either the identity mapping or constant everywhere.

Is this statement true? It feels like it might be, at a first glance, but I have little intuition for these types of statements, so it's unclear if there exists a weird counterexample from adding Choice into the mix.

For now, we can say, for example, that $A = \mathbb{R}$ (though I'm quite curious about the general case as well).

Comment: Take $f(1) = 1$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \neq 1$ for example.

Comment: Note that $f^n(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in A, n \in \Bbb N$ is equivalent to simply saying that $f(f(x)) = f(x)$ for all $x \in A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.  Take $A = \Bbb R$ and $f(x) = |x|$.

---

In general, we can say that if $f(f(x)) = f(x)$, then $f$ is equal to the identity over the image of $f$.  In particular: consider any $y$ in the image of $f$.  Then $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in A$, and we have
$$
f(y) = f(f(x)) = f(x) = y
$$
If $f$ is surjective, then the image of $f$ is $A$, and so $f$ must be the identity map over $A$.

Note that if $f$ is injective, then there exists a function $g(x)$ such that $g(f(x)) = x$, and we have
$$
f(f(x)) = f(x)  \quad \text{for all }x \in A \implies \\
g(f(f(x)) = g(f(x)) \quad \text{for all }x \in A\implies \\
f(x) = x \quad \text{for all }x \in A
$$

Comment: Ah, thank you! Much easier than expected. I do wonder, are there any additional conditions we can add on $f$ for which this *would* imply that it is either constant or the identity? It's unclear to me that this would be the case.

Comment: Ah, brilliant; the latter one was a condition I also managed to scrap together, but didn't formalize. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just take $f$ to be a linear projection, it neither a constant nor the identity.